# How to use Junit 4 with Java 9 modules, Maven and Eclipse?

Tags: maven, junit4, java-9, eclipse-oxygen, java-module

I created a simple Java 9 / Maven project with a Main class and a JUnit 4 test class using the default Maven directory layout.

I have a module-info.java file in the folder src/main/java, Java 9 is configured in the POM. Only Java 9 is used at all places.

The maven build succeeds, the test is executed.

When I import the project to Eclipse (Import existing Maven project, Oxygen.1a), Eclipse complains about JUnit not beeing in the classpath - but it appears in the Maven classpath. Eclipse suggests to add JUnit to the classpath - but that doesn't help either.

(Without module-info.java the Eclipse project works as expected).

Is this an Eclipse issue or should I do a different setup?
Is there an easy workaround?

As I understood, surefire takes some special measures to overcome the problem that test classes are located in a different directory than module-info.java.

How does Eclipse handle this?

Comment: Probably raise this to Eclipse tracker as well.

Comment: Good idea. -> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528360

Comment: It seems surefire will use --patch-module, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1262.